# Does 'The plot thickens' make the game easier or harder?

Tags: the-resistance

Just curious for games going forward.

Because the expansion allows you to see how people have played on missions, can reveal people's cards, etc, it seems like these are all an advantage mostly to the resistance.

In people's experience - does it make it easier for the resistance?

Comment: This will vary depending on your groups play style, It may help, hurt or have no real change at all for the resistance.

Comment: Is there maybe a way you can ask this question to get a definite answer?  It seems too much like an opinion-based question, and questions on this board need to be something that can be fully answered.

Comment: @CrystalBlue A good answer will outline what effect the expansion has, and give a clear 'Yes, it absolutely makes it easier for the Resistance' or a 'No, in my experience the spies learned how to use it to their advantage'.

Answer (score 1):

The Plot Thickens basically adds more opportunities to link players together, thus creating longer and more complex chains of information.
What I mean by chain of information is something like this:

- Player A and Player B both were on a failed mission.
- Player B knows Player C's role card.
- Player C has declared players D and E to play success cards, but their mission with player A failed.

Chains make it easier to deduce information, thus making the Resistance players' role easier. But of course, experienced Spy players can learn to work with, or around, such cards, to confuse people even more.

Tl;dr: The Plot Thickens makes the game more balanced.

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight advantage to *The Resistance* but the plot cards mostly just throw a monkey wrench into the pattern of the game. When you play a game like this repeatedly, you as a group can fall into the same rhythm. Plot cards are designed to interrupt that rhythm. They cause the game to have more chaos and that chaos can in theory help both sides.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree that it makes the game slightly easier for the resistance side, but as a comment mentions it can vary a lot depending on the play style of the group.

In my experience and opinion, it makes the game more strategic and interesting. Since it provides some extra information, allows for a better focusing of the speculation and decision making processes.

After discovering the expansion, I wouldn't play without it unless I'm teaching new people how to play thus making an exception for the first game.